# Interface overriding

Tags: solidity, inheritance, interfaces, override

I have two contracts. One of them inherits another. Inside the parent contract I have the interface

```
interface Token {
    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
}
```

I want to override one inside the child contract to

```
interface Token {
    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) external returns (bool);
    function balanceOf(address who) external view returns (uint256);
}
```

But compiler shows DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.

Is there a way to override an interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any interface can be, by definition, overridden by any real function having that same ABI, but it is not permitted to have N interfaces identical for some member (which precendece in override is not easy defined by inheritance graph!)

In other word if you want to have one interface for the first function, it is not needed to repeat that function identical in a new interface: just collect the other functions required and leave the first interface as is.

Comment: Thanks!
Is it okay to create extended interfaces in the contract which doesn't use some functions?

Comment: No, you should have defined the function written in interface by the contract.

Comment: Even when I use interfaces only for interaction, without implementing them?

Comment: Of course no. In that a case (outbound calls) the methods are implemented somewhere for you and you want to interact with them only. It’s ok.